# How to draw complex cells in DataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Could you explain me how to draw complex cells in DataGrid like on image below?
Do I need a specific control (with TextBlocks) for that or something else?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xE2Q.png `// HTML table example`

Comment: You could create your own (user) control, but you could also create a data template for those cells (in conjunction with [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate.aspx) columns)

Comment: Looks like a `CellTemplate` that contains a `Grid` and a couple of `TextBlock`s. [What have you tried???](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @HighCore I'm new in WPF, and previously did it with Qt TableViews with custom models and delegates.

Comment: you could at least share your data models for the same.